# Cannot read properties of undefined - Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling, undefined

I'm a fairly new user to Apps Script, learning as I go, googling all my questions and ended up here. Very thankful for all the answers I've found thus far. Hopeful you all can help!

I have this script, and the "data.length" line is bringing up "cannot read properties of undefined":

```
    // Function to get data from a given sheet (excluding the first two rows)
function getSheetData(sheet) {
  if (!sheet) {
    return [];
  }
  if (sheet.getLastRow() > 2) {
    return sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}

// Function to write data to the specified sheet with the file name appended
function writeDataToSheet(data, sheet, fileName) {
  if (data.length > 0 && sheet) {
    var numColumns = data[0].length + 1; // Add 1 for the appended file name
    var newData = data.map(function (row) {
      row.push(fileName);
      return row;
    });
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, newData.length, numColumns);
    targetRange.setValues(newData);
  }
}

// Function to consolidate data from sheets within the main folder and update EAS Attempt and DRL Attempt sheets
function consolidateDataAndUpdate() {
  var folderName = "Active Surrogacy Accounts";
  var activeSurrogacyFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();

  var imagineMasterId = "1QrUt9KtaHCc0PmpuEX1tf0DZ-PSRt9wDcsBFXjzuZ_M";
  var imagineMaster = SpreadsheetApp.openById(imagineMasterId);
  Logger.log("Opening Imagine Master spreadsheet");
  var easMasterSheet = imagineMaster.getSheetByName("EAS Attempt");
  var drlMasterSheet = imagineMaster.getSheetByName("DRL Attempt");

  var searchQuery = "title contains 'Escrow Account Statement' and modifiedDate > '2023-06-01' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'";
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchQuery);

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheets();

    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      var sheetName = sheets[i].getName();
      
      if (sheetName.includes("Account Statement")) {
        var easData = getSheetData(sheets[i]);
        if (easData.length > 0) {
          writeDataToSheet(easData, easMasterSheet, fileName);
        }
      } else if (sheetName.includes("Disbursement Request Log")) {
        var drlData = getSheetData(sheets[i]);
        if (drlData.length > 0) {
          writeDataToSheet(drlData, drlMasterSheet, fileName);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know that all sheets exist and are accessible, there are no typos in the names, and from what I can tell the other functions are working properly. -- Obviously chatGPT is not the-end-all-be-all way to learn, though it has been helpful! but it offered this as a solution:  "Check if the sheet parameter being passed to the writeDataToSheet function is null or undefined." Only I have no idea how to do this... and if there might be something else I'm not seeing, or overlooking, that might be better.

I was able to get the code working one night, and then made some change somewhere along the line and tried to replicate it for a similar project, and then it no longer worked again.

Can someone help? Thank you!

Comment: About your issue of `I have this script, and the "data.length" line is bringing up "cannot read properties of undefined":`, unfortunately, your question doesn't show the error line of your script. So, this is just my guess. If the error occurs at `if (data.length > 0) {`, I'm worried that the argument of `data` might not be given. How about confirming the arguments of `data, sheet, fileName` again? If you cannot understand this, can you provide your script of `I was able to get the code working one night`?

Comment: Are you trying to run this function directly in the script editor? Or are you calling this function from another function, and is data defined in that function?

Comment: The line # is 15. All sheets are defined and are correct, I just ran through those again. Oops did not realize enter would submit. the code I got working isn't working anymore either, it says I don't have permission anymore. Im not sure what's going on but I'm looking in to that part. Here is my full script right now. the part I got working was only one sheet. We added the second sheet when we thought it would work. I'll edit my original to update.

Comment: @TheWizEd I updated to show the whole script. Thank you for your assistance. There are 3 functions in the script. Everything is defined in the function consolidateDataAndUpdate .

Comment: Since `getSheetData` always returns an array I can not see what is causing the error.  `easData` and `drlData` are defined.  My only suggestion is to `Logger.log(easData)` before the call to `writeDataToSheet` and then `Logger.log(data)` once in the function.  Do the same for `drlData`.